# Add variables(node) to node depend on a input (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I have two classes like this:

```
public class Block {
    int num;
    int[] array= new int[3];
}
```

And:

```
public class State {
    int[][] Board = new int[6][6];
    Block block1= new Block();
    Block block2= new Block();
    Block block3= new Block();
    Block block4= new Block();
    Block block5= new Block();
    Block block6= new Block();
    Block block7= new Block();
    Block core= new Block();
    State pre;
}
```

But it's too long and not really good. I want to change it to something like: I input an integer N. Then all state will help N block. Anyone have solution for this? (In the example, N is 7.)

Comment: Use a list or a map which hold your block objects.

Comment: An array of blocks might be suitable, Depending on what you want to do.

Comment: The term you want to search for is: **arrays** (which have a fixed size); or **ArrayList** (which is a bit "more complicated")

Comment: in the main class, i will decrale some var with class State like: State state1= new State(); v.v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array in your `State` class to contain the `Block` objects. Then use a method to set the number of `Block` objects and initialise these objects in the array. For example:

```
public class State {
    int[][] Board = new int[6][6];
    Block[] blocks;
    Block core = new Block();
    State pre;

    public void initialiseBlocks(int n) {
        // Initialise the blocks array.
        blocks = new Block[5];

        // Instantiate Block instances in the array.
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            blocks[i] = new Block();
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside, note that it is important to indent code for readability, this makes reading more complex code much easier and reduces the likelihood of bugs occurring.